# How do you create a Spring JPA repository findBy query using a property that contains a keyword?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

Here is a simplified example of my problem.  I have this repository and entity class.

```
public interface ThingRepository extends JpaRepository<ThingEntity, Long> {
    ThingEntity findByFooInAndBar(String fooIn, String bar);
}

@Entity
public class ThingEntity {
    @Column(name="FOO_IN", nullable=false, length=1)
    private String fooIn;

    public String getFooIn() {
        return fooIn;
    }

    public setFooIn(String fooIn) {
        this.fooIn = fooIn;
    }

    /* not including bar property for brevity's sake */
}
```

Spring is throwing the following exception.

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property foo found for type ThingEntity!
```

It looks like Spring is taking the method `findByFooInAndBar` and thinks that `foo` is my property name and `in` is a keyword for matching values within a collection.

How do I get it to understand that the property name is `fooIn`, not `foo`?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to bypass this behavior other than writing your own method. Or just rename the field to `fooin` maybe without the uppercase ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To overcome this problem, I've defined the query manually using the `@Query` annotation.  I'll happily accept anyone else's answer if they find a solution that doesn't require a manual query.

```
public interface ThingRepository extends JpaRepository<ThingEntity, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT t FROM Thing t WHERE t.fooIn = ?1 AND t.bar = ?2")
    ThingEntity findByFooInAndBar(String fooIn, String bar);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Spring is parsing 'In' in your method to create the query. Check the link for create your query: you should change the name of the variable `fooIn` to `fooin` or something like that...

- [Query creation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

Answer (score 1):

I observed the code kindly and notice your return is not a `list` but an `object`.
Change that part to `List<ThingEntity>`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use native sql query which is more easier to use.
**here '?' stands for the parameter that you are passing**.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{
         @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=?",nativeQuery = true)
         public User findByUsername(String username);
}
```