# spring boot CrudRepository findby function could not mapped

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i'm using springboot to create entity and create CRUD function with CrudRepository, i can create findbyHoliday(String name) using @Service 
i really want to make use of springboot CrudRepository, anyone could give me some direction?

here my

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=SPRINGUSER
```

i'm try to create a function extend CrudRepository and heres my interface

**HolidayScheduleRepository.java**

```
public interface HolidayScheduleRepository extends CrudRepository<HolidaySchedule,Long>{
List<HolidaySchedule> findByHDay(@Param("HDay") String hday);

}
```

Heres my entity

**HolidaySchedule.java**

```
@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
@Table(name="TWD_HSD_HOLIDAY_SCHEDULE")
public class HolidaySchedule {
    @Id
    @Column(name="HSD_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer Id;
    @Column(name="HSD_DATE")
    private String HDate;
    @Column(name="HSD_DAY")
    private String HDay;
    @Column(name="HSD_HOLIDAY")
    private String HHoliday;
```

finally my **controller method**

```
@Controller  // This means that this class is a Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/test")
.......
@GetMapping(path="crudtest")
        @ResponseBody
        public List<HolidaySchedule> findHolidayByName(){
            return holidayScheduleRepository.findByHDay("Monday");
        }
```

and **ERROR 81372** shown

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'holidayScheduleController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'holidayScheduleRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'holidayScheduleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create query metamodel for method public abstract java.util.List com.twd.holidayschedule.HolidayScheduleRepository.findByHDay(java.lang.String)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:358) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:574) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:491) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:865) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:809) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:404) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1263) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1252) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.twd.TradingWatchDogApplication.main(TradingWatchDogApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'holidayScheduleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create query metamodel for method public abstract java.util.List com.twd.holidayschedule.HolidayScheduleRepository.findByHDay(java.lang.String)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1701) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:491) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create query metamodel for method public abstract java.util.List com.twd.holidayschedule.HolidayScheduleRepository.findByHDay(java.lang.String)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:106) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:214) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$null$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:410) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$2(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:412) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:403) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:241) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$2(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:258) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:62) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:261) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1697) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [hDay] on this ManagedType [com.twd.holidayschedule.HolidaySchedule]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AbstractManagedType.checkNotNull(AbstractManagedType.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toExpressionRecursively(QueryUtils.java:569) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.getTypedPath(JpaQueryCreator.java:377) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.build(JpaQueryCreator.java:300) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.toPredicate(JpaQueryCreator.java:205) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:117) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:54) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:111) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:78) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:129) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$CountQueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:257) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:72) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
```

Comment: `@Query` takes a JPQL query NOT a SQL query by default. You are trying to write SQL query instead of JPQL query. Also you are trying to select a single column but expect a full object (that isn't going to work either). Also what is the error you get with either approach.

Comment: Don't add additional information as comments. Edit your question and do proper formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tough one, I would highly suggest that you adhere to standard Java conventions such as starting all of your field names with a lower case letter (camelCase format). I believe that is the reason that it is not able to find the field.

You will want it to look like this in the Repository

```
`List<HolidaySchedule> findByHDay(String hDay);`
```

and

`@Column(name="HSD_DAY")
 private String hDay;`

in your model.

Start with this and see where it gets you.

See below for Spring Reference

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.11.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: yes, i tried, it will works too, but i already built a lot entities and database,  and i created a lot extend Repository as @Service

Comment: You don't need to use JPQL if you don't need to... It can autogenerate that query for you just how you name the method in the interface.

Comment: i really want Keep this naming "HST_XXX" in my database , any solution for this?

Comment: Can you clarify? What does that have to do with the question you asked?

Answer (score 1):

One more solution is using native query but better solution is as suggested by **Chad**

```
List<HolidaySchedule> findByHDay(String hDay);`
```

below is the native query for this problem

```
public interface HolidayScheduleRepository extends CrudRepository<HolidaySchedule,Long>{

     @Query("SELECT * FROM TWD_HSD_HOLIDAY_SCHEDULE WHERE HSD_DAY = :hday")
    List<HolidaySchedule> findByHDay(@Param("hday) String hday);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

another approach, works too

Repository:

```
    public interface HolidayScheduleRepository extends CrudRepository<HolidaySchedule,Long>{

     @Query("SELECT hs FROM HolidaySchedule hs WHERE hs.HDay = ?1")
    List<HolidaySchedule> findByHDay( String hday);

}
```

in the controller, jsut @autowired and use it, it will works

refer to this
[How do you create a Spring JPA repository findBy query using a property that contains a keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153271/how-do-you-create-a-spring-jpa-repository-findby-query-using-a-property-that-con?answertab=votes#tab-top)